# Powershell - Get-WinEvent

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, get-winevent

I have been looking all over the place to just figure out what this "Level" means running Get-WinEvent.

For example,

```
Get-WinEvent –FilterHashtable @{logname=’application’; level=2; starttime=$time; id=20}
```

What does `level=2` represent here?
The reason that I am asking is I am trying to validate the severity of each log and does that `level=2` represent anything related to severity.

Answer (score 6):

Let's try and find out:

```
#Get sample object
$t = Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterHashtable @{ Logname='application'; level=2 }

#Explore properties and type
$t.GetType().Fullname
System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
```

A quick msdn-search for [EventLogRecord](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogrecord(v=vs.110).aspx) points us to the [EventLogRecord.Level Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogrecord.level(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the level of the event. The level signifies the severity of the
>   event. For the name of the level, get the value of the
>   LevelDisplayName property

```
#Check out Level vs LevelDisplayName
$t | Format-Table -Property Level, LevelDisplayName -AutoSize

Level LevelDisplayName
----- ----------------
    2 Error
```

A quick search in my log to list some level-values:

```
Get-WinEvent @{ logname='application' } | Select-Object Level, LevelDisplayName -Unique | Sort-Object Level

Level LevelDisplayName
----- ----------------
    0 Information     
    2 Error           
    3 Warning         
    4 Information
```

It also says on the Level-property page that it uses the `StandardEventLevel` enum, so lets list it's values:

```
[enum]::GetValues([System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.StandardEventLevel]) | Select-Object {$_}, {$_.value__ }

           $_ $_.value__ 
           -- -----------
    LogAlways           0
     Critical           1
        Error           2
      Warning           3
Informational           4
      Verbose           5
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new to powershell. Just looking for specific information is hard. and I really appreciate for your time.

Comment: Even better reason for me to describe the full journey to the answer then. :-) You learn by trying, failing and asking questions like you're doing now. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: If you consider this the correct answer, please use the checkmark to the left of the answer so we can mark the question as solved. :-)

Answer (score 0):

See this link for more info. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd996917(v=vs.85))

Effectively you're looking for a winmeta.xml file, but it'll have these for the base values :

- LogAlways: 0,
- Critical: 1,
- Error: 2,
- Warning: 3,
- Information: 4,
- Verbose: 5,
- rest below 16 are reserved

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated.